# How to get and set center location of a leaflet (proxy) map in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shiny-reactivity, r-leaflet

I would like to retrieve the current center location as well as set it in the same `numericInput`. I am able to achieve it in general, however, when changing the input field, leaflet struggles to get to a stable position but bounces back and forth.

I also tried to include a short delay (`throttle()`/`debounce()`) to circumvent the problem yet this has proven unsuccessful. Any ideas how I can get it to work both ways?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
  numericInputIcon(inputId = "longitude",
                   label = "Longitude",
                   icon = icon("arrows-alt-h"),
                   min = -180,
                   max = 180,
                   value = 18,
                   step = .1),
  numericInputIcon(inputId = "latitude",
                   label = "Latitude",
                   icon = icon("arrows-alt-v"),
                   min = -90,
                   max = 90,
                   value = 50,
                   step = .1)
  ),
  leafletOutput("map")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = isolate(input$longitude),
              lat = isolate(input$latitude),
              zoom = 3)
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_center, {
    updateNumericInputIcon(session = session,
                           inputId = "longitude",
                           value = round(input$map_center$lng, 1))
    updateNumericInputIcon(session = session,
                           inputId = "latitude",
                           value = round(input$map_center$lat, 1))
  })


  # with delay -------------------------------------
  updateMap <- reactive({
    leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
      setView(lng = input$longitude,
              lat = input$latitude,
              zoom = 3)
  })

  updateMap_t <- updateMap %>% throttle(1000)

  observe(updateMap_t())

  # without any delay ------------------------------
  # observe({
  #   leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
  #     setView(lng = input$longitude,
  #             lat = input$latitude,
  #             zoom = 3)
  # })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Side Note: I do not want to render the complete map again since this takes some time. Therefore, leafletProxy

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is curious, when applying the delay to the numericInput rather than the map update, it is much more stable and actually usable. There is still a small shake but this is salvagable IMO. Any other suggestions are still appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    numericInputIcon(inputId = "longitude",
                     label = "Longitude",
                     icon = icon("arrows-alt-h"),
                     min = -180,
                     max = 180,
                     value = 18,
                     step = .1),
    numericInputIcon(inputId = "latitude",
                     label = "Latitude",
                     icon = icon("arrows-alt-v"),
                     min = -90,
                     max = 90,
                     value = 50,
                     step = .1)
  ),
  leafletOutput("map")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = isolate(input$longitude),
              lat = isolate(input$latitude),
              zoom = 3)
  })



  # update Input with delay
  map_long <- eventReactive(input$map_center$lng, {
    input$map_center$lng
  })%>% debounce(1000)
  map_lat <- eventReactive(input$map_center$lat, {
    input$map_center$lat
  })%>% debounce(1000)

  observe({
    updateNumericInputIcon(session = session,
                           inputId = "longitude",
                           value = round(map_long(), 1))
    updateNumericInputIcon(session = session,
                           inputId = "latitude",
                           value = round(map_lat(), 1))
  })


  # without any delay
  observe({
    leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
      setView(lng = input$longitude,
              lat = input$latitude,
              zoom = 3)
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```